# Existence of a function $y(x)$ satisfying $y''(x)-q(x)y(x)=0$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a function $q(x)>0$ which is monotonically increasing in $[0,\infty)$ and the second order ODE $y''(x)-q(x)y(x)=0$ with $y(0)=y'(0)=1$. Using Strum comparison theorem it is clear that $y(x)$ has no zeroes in $[0,\infty)$ and $Lim_{x→\infty}y(x)→\infty$ but how to conclude that $ Lim_{x→\infty} y'(x)→\infty$?

**What I tried:**The least monotonically increasing function must be $q(x)=x$ which on plugging into the given ODE gives $y(x)$ as an infinite series in positive powers of $x$, which verifies the result. Am I right to generalize this or am I missing some concrete logic?
 Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you tell me please that how $y\rightarrow\infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)=\infty$, there exists an $M>1$, such that 
$$
x\ge M\quad\Longrightarrow\quad y(x)\ge 1,
$$
and as $q$ is increasing, then $p(x)y(x)\ge p(M)y(M)$, for all $x\ge M$, and thus

$$
y'(t)=y'(M)+\int_M^xy''(s)\,ds=y'(M)+\int_M^x p(s)\,y(s)\,ds\ge 
y'(M)+\int_M^xp(M)y(M)\,dx \\  =y'(M)+p(M)y(M)(x-M).
$$
Note finally that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}y'(M)+p(M)y(M)(x-M)=\infty.
$$

Comment: thanks Yiorgos S. Smyrlis..i think some text is missing in ur post.

Comment: I have fixed it now!